# VPN window doesn't apear

Tags: vpn

I'm a new Ubuntu user and i use it alongside win 7. I've done some update and since then I've not been able to use my VPN connection. I click on it and it doesn't even show any window.
How can i make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem to me. Were you able to solve it?